# How to fix thymleaf error with request mapping?

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I am trying to do a print to the screen with some information and to add some elements to an array when a user clicks a button in the front-end. However when I attempt to do this in `Thymleaf` and click the button, then nothing shows up. I tried different combinations to see what works but I couldn't find anything to do this simple task. I tried `th:href` but when I try that it throws an error saying it can't find the file. FYI, I am trying to run this method without refreshing the site.

**Java:**

```
@RequestMapping("/createSelector")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCreationSelector() {

        selectorList.add(new Selector());
        System.out.println(selectorList.size());
        return selectorList.size()+ "";

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/createSelector" class="selectorBtn"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-block eNew"> New Tier</button></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".selectorBtn").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code as below

```
$(".selectorBtn").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.get("createSelector", function( data ) {
                    alert( "Load was performed." );
                });
           });
```

Comment: it will call back-end method asynchronous way & get response. data will have response data.